# Argument of type "Literal['x']" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__"

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code could be simplified to this:

```
from typing import Union, Any, Dict, List, Tuple

def myFunc() -> Union[Dict, List, str,
                      int, float, bool, None]:
  something = { 'prop': 123}
  return something

obj = myFunc()
obj['k'] = isinstance(obj, Dict) and 321
```

and I got the exception from Pylance like this:

```
(variable) obj: object | List | str | int | float | bool | Dict | None
"__setitem__" method not defined on type "object"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
"__setitem__" method not defined on type "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
"__setitem__" method not defined on type "int"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
"__setitem__" method not defined on type "float"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
"__setitem__" method not defined on type "bool"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
Argument of type "Literal['k']" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__"
  "Literal['k']" is incompatible with "slice"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: `Union[object,...]` is pretty much identical to `object`, since *everything* is an instance of object via inheritance.

Comment: The code is going to fail at runtime even if `isinstance(obj, Dict)` is false. `and` only applies to the evaluation of the right-hand side, not to the the attempt to assign to `obj['k']`.

Comment: What you want is a regular `if` statement: `if isinstance(obj, dict): obj['k'] = 123`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the assumption that `obj['k']` can always be valid, but this is not the case for the obj of the types `List | str | int | float | bool | None`. The solution is to rewrite the last line as follows:

```
obj = isinstance(obj, Dict) and {**obj, 'k': 123}
```

The complete example is below:

```
from typing import Union, Any, Dict, List, Tuple

def myFunc() -> Union[object, Dict, List, str,
                      int, float, bool, None]:
  something = { 'prop': 123}
  return something

obj = myFunc()
obj = isinstance(obj, Dict) and {**obj, 'k': 123}
```

Comment: Why make a new `dict`? You could just as easily perform the type check and then do the item assignment if it passes. With `and`, you'll throw away any non-`dict` and replace it with `False`, further confusing the static typing. `if isinstance(obj, dict): obj['k'] = 123` would do the trick without type confusion and needless copies.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger, `if isinstance(obj, dict): obj['k'] = 123` is another working option